# Plotting Problem with DataArray ax.set_title

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, python-xarray

i have a DataArray variable called "iav" that has shape (12, 441, 1440) with 12 months of data. I am trying to plot each month in a loop in a 4 row by 3 col figure one month at a time in the figure. The final figure is correct except that when the line "ax.set_title(f'month = {d}') is executed, the unwanted text data is printed on top of the figures. W/out this line, the unwanted text data is gone but so too is the month title.

Here is the figure I'm seeing now -

[image]

Here is my code for the plotting part -

```
#standard deviation / monthly wind speed average from climo
iav = ((stdwind.groupby('month') / wind_abs_clim))

#sel = iav.sel(month=slice('1', None))

left, *_, right = iav.longitude
top, *_, bottom = iav.latitude  # Min and max latitude.
extent = [left, right, bottom, top]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=3,
                        figsize=(15, 10),
                        subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()},
                       )

for ax, d in zip(axs.flat, iav):
    #
    im = ax.imshow(d,
                   transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                   extent=extent,
                   cmap='RdBu_r', vmin=0, vmax=1)
    ax.set_title(f'month = {d}')
    ax.coastlines()

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,
                    bottom=0.1, 
                    right=0.9, 
                    top=0.4, 
                    wspace=0.05, 
                    hspace=0.3)

Size = fig.get_size_inches()
fig.set_size_inches(Size[1]*2, Size[1]*2)
#fig.set_figheight(12.0)
#fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 15.5)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.0, 0.6, 0.02])  # Left, bottom, width, height.
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cbar_ax, extend='both', orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_label('Inter-Annual Variability')
    
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the line ax.set_title(f'month = {d}') is that "d" is a dataarray and each time through the loop, the entire dataarray text contents was printing on top of the figures. Here is my solution to create an integer for each month 1 - 12.

```
i = 1
for ax, d in zip(axs.flat, iav):
    #
    im = ax.imshow(d,
                   transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                   extent=extent,
                   cmap='RdBu_r', vmin=0, vmax=1)
    ax.set_title(f'month = {i}')
    i += 1
    ax.coastlines()
```

[image]